# How am I able to check what triggered a process to run at a certain time?

Tags: process, top

I'm seeing a process popping up every 6h in one of my machines. I've checked the cron files and no user has anything that would trigger a cron job every 6h.
I'm trying to understand what is triggering the specific job to start and stop every 6h at a specific time, that only runs a couple of minutes, and uses a bunch of memory.
Unfortunately the name of the process alone is not helping. Is there any way I can check the history of process that ran during a specific time and see what triggered them to start?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check in `/etc/cron`, did you check in `/var/log/cron`?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I couldn't find anything that matched the timeframe

Comment: if you know times of occurence, run multiple `ps -ef -H > file.xxx` you may catch process father.

Comment: @Ress, is it possible some software, which run on the machine to have own scheduler and run something?